# Bootstrap Accordion, set the style for the active head panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to set a style to the active position 'panel heading' as this:
[image]

I want to add the background color and font-weight for the active panel... and that icon stood in the down position...
What i have (my code) : `http://www.bootply.com/wZrFTAIRfe`

P.S. sorry for my english..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading[aria-expanded="true"] {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #99ccff;
    background-image: url(http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0724/h_1469363621_2952426_312a0c7b35.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to css

```
[aria-expanded="true"] .panel-title
{
background-color: blue;
font-weight: 600;
}
```